# Is product of two linear combinations over a finite field information hiding?

Tags: elliptic-curves, finite-field, linear-cryptanalysis

Suppose we have a 32-bit message $ M=(m_1,..m_{32}) \in \{0, 1\}^{32} $ and we have secrets $ F_{i, b} $ and $ G_{i, b} $ (2x32+2x32=128 secrets in total).

$$ \forall 1 \leq i \leq 32, b \in \{0, 1\} : F_{i, b}, G_{i, b} \in Z_q $$

And now we define two functions $ f $ and $ g $ respectively:

$$ f(m_1, .., m_{32})= \sum_{i=1}^{32}{F_{i, m_i}} $$
$$ g(m_1, .., m_{32})= \sum_{i=1}^{32}{G_{i, m_i}} $$

We say $ h(M) = f(M) * g(M) $, and we publish the evaluations of $ h $ for every possible message, how many distinct tuples of $ (M, h(M)) $ is needed for an adversary to be able to recover the secrets $ F_{i, b}, G_{i, b} $? Or can we assume that the function $ h $ is information hiding regarding $ F, G $?

I would appreciate any references or hint about which part of the literature I should look into!

(P.S: we're doing all of this in a finite field, the implementation should use curve secp256k1/r1 in practice)

Comment: Hmmmm, when you say $ h = f \times g $, do you mean cross product (that is, $h$ consists of the value $f$ and the value $g$), or do you mean finite field multiplication?  I didn't think you meant multiplication, because there's no equivalent operation if you move to an elliptic curve

Comment: @poncho $ h(M) = f(M) * g(M) $, i should have noted that $ F, G \in Z $

Comment: If $*$ is a multiplication operation, how are you intended to do that operation when you use the curve secp256k1/r1?

Comment: the elements $F_{i, b}$ and $G_{i, b}$ are scalar values, so the value of both $ f(M) $ and $ f(M) $ is also an scalar, i'm only using the finite field of the secp256, not the points.

Comment: So, you're using the field that sec256k1/r1 is defined on, and are not doing any elliptic curve additions/etc at all?

Comment: @poncho yes, that's correct.

Comment: Hmmmm, is the goal of the attacker necessarily the recovery of the secret values (note that there are a number of symmetries that prevent someone recovering the exact values)?  Or, would it be sufficient if the attacker could compute $h(M)$ for values of $M$ that he did not query?

Comment: @poncho yes, that's also not desirable, if you're interested in where this is being used, it's for a possible improvement to the GS22 threshold ECDSA protocol, [see here](https://qti3e.notion.site/Dealing-reuse-resistant-GS22-f7ffcf90fc194d399548b147920dc02d) for broader context

Answer (score 1):

> would it be sufficient if the attacker could compute $h(M)$ for values of $M$ that he did not query?

> yes, that's also not desirable

Ok, here's one (not likely to be optimal approach) to do that, which succeeds with good probability for an attacker chosen message given 529 random $M, H(M)$ pairs.

We can rewrite $h(M)$ as follows:

$$h(m) = \sum_{i : m_i \ne 0} c_i + \sum_{i, j : i < j \land m_i, m_j \ne 0} d_{i,j} + e$$

with the assignments:

$$F_{i,\Delta} = F_{i,1} - F_{i,0}$$
$$G_{i,\Delta} = G_{i,1} - G_{i,0}$$
$$c_i = F_{i,\Delta}G_{i,\Delta} + F_{i,\Delta} \sum_k G_{k,0} + G_{i,\Delta} \sum_k F_{k,0}$$
$$d_{i,j} = F_{i,\Delta}G_{j,\Delta} + F_{j,\Delta}G_{i,\Delta}$$
$$e = \sum_k F_{k,0} \cdot \sum_k G_{k,0}$$

The attacker knows, for any message $M$, which values of $c_i, d_{i,j}, e$ which need to be added together to create the sum.  There are a total of 529 such values (32 $c_i$ values, 496 $d_{i,j}$ values and 1 $e$ value); if he has 529 random $M$ values (with the appropriate sum), he has a good chance of being able, for another message $M'$, being able to use linear algebra to find the appropriate sum from the equations he knows.

Now, this is likely not the best possible approach; after all, there are only 128 secrets, and so in theory, it should be computable with that many (and actually less; there are symmetries where a number of sets of secret values give the same output).  However, this gives one upper limit on how many $h(M)$ values you can publish.

Comment: Thank you! I updated the question to note that $ H(M) = F(M) * G(M) $, how about that case?

Comment: this makes sense! thank you for the help xD, sadly i can't upvote yet :(